# How to update the browser's cache after adding html to page with Ajax

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax

I am developing a `java spring portlet (Liferay)` application and have a page where a user can fill in a form.  There is a section where they can add images and these get injected into the page by `ajax` calls.
When they click save, they are presented with a preview page.

The issue is that if they then use the browser back button, the images are not stored in the browser's copy of the previous page.

Is there a way to force the browser to update its copy of the dom at the point where the page gets saved?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

no, you cannot change the value of an `<input type="file">`

There is only one possible solution I can imagine:

Add the file, read its content to an base64 string and store it into the [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) of your Browser. But this will only work in modern browser.